# Issue about installing libgtk-3-dev on Debian 10 arm64

Tags: opencv, debian

I need use OpenCV3.4.1 on Debian 10 which is arm64 embedded system.
When I chroot and try to install libgtk-3-dev with command:

'''
apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev
'''

I get error:

> ...
>
> *Err:1 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 libpam-systemd arm64 241-7~deb10u3
>     404  Not Found [IP: 133.5.166.3 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_241-7~deb10u3_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 133.5.166.3 80]

but apt-get install libgtk-3-dev --fix-missing can't fix this issue.*

I did double check and find the file is NOT existed.
I also download similar file libpam-systemd_241-7~deb10u4_arm64.deb and try to install it with command:
 'dpkg -i libpam-systemd_241-7~deb10u4_arm64.deb'

below is the error information:

> *dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:arm64:
>
> *libpam-systemd:arm64 depends on systemd (= 241-7~deb10u4); however:
>    Version of systemd on system is 241-7~deb10u3.
>   dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:arm64 (--install):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    libpam-systemd:arm64**

How can I fix this issue?

Any recommendation will be welcomed.

Comment: please show us your apt repositories

Comment: Similar question:
    `apt-get install packagekit-gtk3-module`
gives

    Failed to fetch `http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_241-7~deb10u4_amd64.deb`
Sources:
```cat /etc/apt/sources.list```
Gives
```deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main```

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gtk+3.0/libgtk-3-dev_3.24.5-1_amd64.deb

dpkg -i libgtk-3-dev_3.24.5-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26177426)

Answer (score 0):

I built this rootfs a couple of months ago, today I rebuild it from debootstrap and I can install  libgtk-3-dev in new rootfs now, it seems that my rootfs is too old to install the package.